# How can I use AWS's Dynamo Db with Django?

Tags: python, django, orm, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing web applications, APIs, and backends using the Django MVC framework. A major aspect of Django is its implementation of an ORM for models. It is an exceptionally good ORM. Typically when using Django, one utilizes an existing interface that maps one's Django model to a specific DBMS like Postgres, MySQL, or Oracle for example.

I have some specific needs, requirements regarding performance and scalability, so I really want to use AWS's Dynamo DB because it is highly cost efficient, very performant, and scales really well.

While I think Django allows one to implement their own interface for a DBMS if one wishes to do so, it is clearly advantageous to be able to use an existing DBMS interface when constructing one's Django models if one exists.

Can someone recommend a Django model interface to use so I can construct a model in Django that uses AWS's Dynamo DB?

How about one using MongoDB?

Comment: Afaik, there's no Django DB backend for DyanmoDB; There's a third party for DB backend for MongoDB ( https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ). There''s also PynamoDB ( https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB ) which might come in handy.

Comment: A great question - the lack of official NoSQL ORM support by Django is becoming a liability. True, not all NoSQL's are alike but support for say the big 5 like they support the various flavors of SQL (maria, postgres, mysql, oracle, sqlite) would be nice. As an FYI - I use Djongo for Django with MOngoDB often. It works pretty well but  its limited to Mongodb.

Answer (score 12):

As written by others, Django does not have NoSQL DBMS support, but there are third-party packages.

[PynamoDB](https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB) seems fine, but I have never used it, so I can’t recommend it. In all use cases I came across, boto3 was sufficient. Setup is pretty simple, but the devil is in details (in the data structure and how nested it is, to be precise). Basically, three steps are needed:

1. Connect with the DB and perform the operation you want ([boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html))
2. Parse incoming data into a Python dictionary (e.g. with [dynamodb-json](https://github.com/Alonreznik/dynamodb-json), [boto3.dynamodb.types.TypeDeserializer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html) or you can build your own)
3. Do business logic, store data into relational DB using the Django ORM or whatever you need

Simplest example:

```
from dynamodb_json import json_util as dynamodb_json
from .models import YourModel

def get(request, partition_key):
    table = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb',
        aws_access_key_id=...,
        aws_secret_access_key=...,
        region_name=...,
    ).Table(some_table_name)
    try:
        response = table.get_item(
            Key={partition_key: partition_key})
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.warning(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        data_str = response['Item']
        _data_dict = dynamodb_json.loads(data_str)

        # Validation and modification of incoming data goes here.
        data_dict = validation_and_modification(_data_dict)
        # Then you can do whatever you need, for example:
        obj, created = YourModel.objects.update_or_create(**data_dict)
        ...
```

Examples for create, delete, list and update views can be found in the [serverless repo](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-dynamodb/todos).

Answer (score 4):

It's not like ready made battery for django, but worth looking at it regardless.
https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB

Comment: I was confused by reading the docs of PynamoDB. Is PynamoDB based off of boto, boto3, or botocore? Is there a downside to using PynamoDB over boto3? I'm trying to figure out if it's better to use boto3 or PynamoDB. Thanks!

Comment: PynamoDB is using `botocore` under the hood - https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/blob/master/setup.py#L5  
If you fancy writing your own functions to read/write the records then you can go with boto3. I tried PynamoDB and it worked fine for my use case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [DynamORM](https://github.com/NerdWalletOSS/dynamorm) or [PynamoDB](https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB). I haven't tried them maybe they can help.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is non-relational which I think makes it architecturally incompatible with an ORM like Django's.

Comment: You can use any database if it has compatible ORM and configured properly in `settings.py`. For example MongoDB.

Comment: @wowkin2 sure, you can use any ORM you want. Though, OP was asking about using the Django ORM with a non-relational backend, which is fundamentally not compatible, as rcx correctly states in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Django model interface for AWS DynamoDB, but you may retrieve data from that kind of db using boto3 software provided by AWS.