# Can we use DynamoDB database with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, amazon-dynamodb

I have to work on the project in which I have to use Django Rest Framework with DynamoDB database. Can I use them together? If not - then what are the reasons behind it?

Comment: Did you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976471/how-can-i-use-awss-dynamo-db-with-django

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this step:

**step 1** - Install Amazon SDK (https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/)

**step 2** - see the example of a query here: https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dynamodb_tut.html

**step 3** - Then you need to parse a response in your API.